# cannot find path to control angular 13.0.0 with TS

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I know it's been asked but I seem to have it set up right and still have an error with my angular form.

Cannot find control with path: 'builderPreferences -> idx -> groupId'
and
Cannot find control with path: 'builderPreferences -> idx -> manufacturerId'

I have the form group and array builder in TS as such:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-builder-detail',
  templateUrl: './builder-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./builder-detail.component.scss']
})
export class BuilderDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  builderId?: number;
  groups?: any[];
  manufacturers?: any[];
  builder = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      builderPreferences: this.formBuilder.array([]),
  });



  get builderPreferences(): UntypedFormArray {
    return this.builder.get('builderPreferences') as UntypedFormArray;
  }



  deletePreference(index: number) {
    this.builderPreferences.removeAt(index);
  }

  constructor(
    @Optional() @Inject(API_VERSION) private apiVersion: string,
    public modalRef: BsModalRef,
    private formBuilder: UntypedFormBuilder,
    private buildersApiService: BuildersApiService,
    private groupsApiService: GroupsApiService,
    private manufacturersApiService: ManufacturersApiService,
    private loader: LoadingService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.builderId) this.loadDetail();
  }

  async loadDetail() {
    let builder = await this.buildersApiService.Get({
      path: {
        version: this.apiVersion,
        id: this.builderId ?? 0
      }
    }).toPromise();

    this.builder.patchValue(builder);

    if (builder.builderPreferences) {
      let processedPreferences = this.formBuilder.array([]);

    for (let idx = 0; idx < builder.builderPreferences.length; idx++) {
       
  processedPreferences.push(this.formBuilder.group(builder.builderPreferences[idx]))
  }

  this.builder.setControl('builderPreferences', processedPreferences);
 }
}

 newPreference() {
   this.builderPreferences.push(this.formBuilder.group({
     groupId: [],
  manufacturerId: [], 
 }));
}


async save(close: boolean = false) {
this.loader.start();
let call;

if (this.builderId) {
  call = await this.buildersApiService.Update({
    body: this.builder.value,
    path: {
      version: this.apiVersion,
      id: this.builderId ?? 0
    }
  }).toPromise();
 } else {
  call = await this.buildersApiService.Create({
    body: this.builder.value,
    path: {version: this.apiVersion}
  }).toPromise();
  }

    this.builder.markAsPristine();
    this.loader.stop();

    if (!this.builderId) this.builderId = call.id;
  }
}
```

And the html file is as such:

```
<form autocomplete="off" [formGroup]="builder">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="row g-3">
    <div class="col-12">
     <label class="form-label" for="name">Name</label>
     <input formControlName="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
   </div>

<div class="section back-charges">
  <h4>Preferences</h4>
   <ul class="amount-list" *ngIf="builderPreferences?.length" 
    formArrayName="builderPreferences" >
     <li *ngFor="let builderPreference of builderPreferences.controls; let idx = index">  
       <div class="row g-3" formGroupName="idx">
        <div class="col-3">
         <select formControlName="groupId" class="form-control mb-3">
           <option value="undefined" selected>Select Group</option>
            <option *ngFor="let group of groups"
              value="{{ group.id }}">
              {{ group.name }}
            </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <select formControlName="manufacturerId" class="form-control mb-3">
          <option value="undefined" selected>-- Select Manufacturer / Division -- 
           </option>
          <option *ngFor="let manufacturer of manufacturers"
              value="{{ manufacturer.id }}">
              {{ manufacturer.name }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1">
        <button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-text" 
        (click)="deletePreference(idx)">
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
          </button>
        </div>         
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul> 
  <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" (click)="newPreference()">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Preference
  </button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: when does the error occur ? on populating data or once you try to save it ?

Comment: @millenion didnt think to mention that. it is when populating the data. so when add preference is triggered new emtpy fields are created and thats when the error pops up. it will not even save the data due to this.

Comment: It's out of the question, but the code looks like better if you choose use Observables instead of promises. Believe me, the Observables are more "comfortables" that this "ugly" await and Promises

Comment: good idea but unfortunately have to follow current code set up to stay uniformed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error when looking at this link - looks like I was missing some binding!

https://dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2022/01/05/how-to-use-angular-formarrays-within-formgroups-in-reactive-forms/

swapped the ul from formArrayName to [formArrayName]

```
  <ul class="amount-list" *ngIf="builderPreferences?.length" 
    [formArrayName]="builderPreferences" >
```

and the option to this:

```
<option *ngFor="let group of groups"
   [ngValue]="group.id">
      {{ group.name }}
</option>
```